# mouse position property set mouse position according to whole screen instead current windows form

Tags: c#, winforms

Hello I  have a windows form. I want to show a popup at the position of mouse  but when I get the mouse position with mouseposition property,it doesnt show right below the cursor.
When I click the cell the popup should appear right below the cursor instead it shows at random places
[image]

I have a code like this:

```
Point p = new Point();
        p = MousePosition;
        if (e.Column.Name=="colnot_detay") 
        {
           labelControl1.Text=gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle,"not_detay").ToString();
           popupContainerControl2.Location = p;
           popupContainerControl2.Show();
           
        }
```

Comment: [Control.PointToClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient) <-> [Control.PointToScreen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoscreen)

Comment: p = popupContainerControl2.Parent.PointToClient(MousePosition);

Comment: this solved my problem thank you